# Error while doing IdP initiated login using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, onelogin, idp

I am using IdP as Onelogin & aws cognito(SP). SP initiated login working fine. But when i clicked on App Portal/ Home -> on my application, then it redirects to cognito with error prompt "**Invalid relayState from identity provider**"
I checked relay state parameter in One-Login configuration is correct like https://***:81/login which is our login page URL.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cognito only supports SP initiated flow.

So the flow must go Cognito Authorize endpoint -> IDP -> back to Cognito.

Comment: You need to login using the Cognito Authorize endpoint such as https://yourDomainPrefix.auth.region.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&identity_provider=samlProviderName&client_id=yourClientId&redirect_uri=redirectUrl&scope=allowedOauthScopes

Comment: Yes! That's mentioned in the article [SAML session initiation in Amazon Cognito user pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-SAML-session-initiation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of [February 2024](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/02/amazon-cognito-signing-encryption-identity-provider-initiated-sso/), Cognito does support the IDP initiated flow.
If you are using IDP-initiated SAML, you need to update the format of your Relay State. Refer to my answer here for more details on how to enable this within cognito: [AWS Cognito: support of SSO IdP-initiated workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185108/aws-cognito-support-of-sso-idp-initiated-workflow/78156116#78156116)